# How to get the URL to a configurable item in Magento?

Tags: php, url, magento

I am using magento and creating a product finder. Is there a way I can link to a configurable item example: **mystore.com/bedding-sheets**

lets say I want to send a friend a link to the sheet that is 250*250cm i would think the link was maybe: **mystore.com/bedding-sheets?attribute496=1** (except this is not the case)

```
<dl class="last">
    <dt><label>Size<span class="required"> *</span></label></dt>
     <dd class="last">
     <select class="required-entry super-attribute-select" id="attribute496" name="super_attribute[496]">
      <option value="">Choose option...</option>
      <option value="4">200*200cm</option>
      <option value="3">200*230cm</option>
      <option value="2">200*250cm</option>
      <option value="1">250*250cm</option></select>
    </dd>
</dl>
```

Anyone know if it's possible to create such a link?

**EDIT:** So i was able to find out how to add an item to my cart using **/checkout/cart/add?product=47&qty=1&super_attribute[496]=4**

however I want the user to get a preview of the item they will receive, instead of just dumping it into the cart.

Comment: First of all: Could you tell us what kind of options you need to be able to specify in the url? Quantity? Input fields? Preselect select boxes? Dates? Those are different things in Magento you know.

Comment: Options of a select box, a configurable item.

Comment: Okay, in that case did you try what I described in my answer? It should enable you to do exactly what you want to do! If you run into trouble let me know.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not possible to do this without making changes to Magento.

Now suppose you wanted to predefine the selected options of a select box in the url:

First you need to overwrite the block *Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_View_Options_Type_Select*. (I assume that you have created your own module already - I you haven't and need help with that let me know)

To do this you need to add this entry to your config.xml:

```
<config>
    <global>
        <blocks>
            <catalog>
                <rewrite>
                    <product_view_options_type_select>YourCompany_YourModuleName_Product_View_Options_Type_Select</product_view_options_type_select>
                </rewrite>
            </catalog>
        </blocks>
    </global>
</config>
```

Next add  the class *YourCompany_YourModuleName_Product_View_Options_Type_Select* which needs to extend *Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_View_Options_Type_Select*.

In this class you must now overwrite the function *getValuesHtml()*. To start off you should copy it from the class you're extending.

In this function you should find this `foreach`:

```
    foreach ($_option->getValues() as $_value) {
        $priceStr = $this->_formatPrice(array(
            'is_percent' => ($_value->getPriceType() == 'percent') ? true : false,
            'pricing_value' => $_value->getPrice(true)
        ), false);
        $select->addOption(
            $_value->getOptionTypeId(),
            $_value->getTitle() . ' ' . $priceStr . ''
        );
    }
```

After this you add:

```
$standardValue = $this->getRequest()->getParam($_option->getid());
//Mage::log("Option Name: "$_option->getid());
$select->setValue($standardValue);
```

This should do it. Unfortunately I can't test this right now. So let me know if you run into troubles.

I'm not sure if the `$_option->getid()` is the right name for your parameter. But you could try to find that out if you comment in the one line I commented out for you in the code listing from above.
In your Magento installation open the file *var/log/system.log* where the name of your url parameters should now appear.

Now that you know the how to name the url parameters you can do exactly what you wanted: *url/to/product?option_id=value_id*

PS: If you ask yourself why we create a new class instead of changing it directly in the Magento core: We do this to prevent problems when updating to a new version of Magento.

I hope I could help.

Comment: This solution wont work, I deleted this class **Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_View_Options_Type_Select** and configurable product sheet is working fine , which prove that any override if this class will not give any resultats